# Dynamically allocate a vector using new keyword

Tags: c++, vector, stl, containers, c++17

I was wondering if it is possible to dynamically allocate a vector using new keyword, similar to an array.

what I mean is this:

```
vector<int> *vptr = new vector<int>;
```

I could not find proper reference about this problem over the internet.
I would like to know what the below statement means. Both are valid syntax.
Also how to dereference the pointer here.

```
vector<int> *vptr = new vector<int>[10];
vector<int> *vptr1 = new vector<int>(2,5);
```

Comment: You can, although there's not usually a good reason to do so. The first line creates an array of 10 empty vectors and the second creates a single vector containing two 5s. You would dereference these pointers as you would any other pointer.

Comment: If you understand what `int *ptr = new int[10];` means you should be able to understand what it mean in your example as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    // v is pointer toward a vector<int>
    vector<int> *v = new vector<int>();
    // So we should use '->' to dereference
    // and use the method push_back
    v->push_back(1);
    v->push_back(2);
    v->push_back(3);
    for (auto i = 0u; i < v->size(); i++) {
        // we are using at method to access 
        // elements as it is more readable 
        // than (*v)[i]
        cout << v->at(i) << endl;
    }
    // v1 is an array of vector<int>
    vector<int> *v1 = new vector<int>[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // we access to the ith vector with 
        // the [] operator same way we deal 
        // with other arrays. v[i] is of type 
        // vector so we use directly the push_back method
        v1[i].push_back(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << v1[i][0] << endl;
    }
    delete [] v1;
    
    // same as v
    vector<int> *v2 = new vector<int>(2, 3);
    for (auto i = 0u; i < v2->size(); i++) {
        cout << v2->at(i) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you immensely. Actually, this is what i was looking for and the code that you provided really helps in my understanding. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

First things first, creating `std::vector` dynamically(like you do in the example) should not be your first choice.

> I would like to know what the below statement means

Let's look at them one by one.

##### Case 1

Here we consider the statement:

```
vector<int> *vptr = new vector<int>[10];
```

This creates 10 empty `std::vector<int>`s and initialize the pointer `vptr` with the pointer to the very first of those dynamically created vectors. You can compare this with `int *ptr = new int[10];`.

##### Case 2

Here we consider the statment:

```
vector<int> *vptr1 = new vector<int>(2,5);
```

This creates a single `std::vector<int>` of size `2` with each of its elements initialized to `5` and then the pointer `vptr` is initialized with the pointer to that dynamically created vector.